# 1N5821 Schottky diode material

Tags: diodes, schottky, materials

Is the 1N5821 Schottky diode made of silicon? Or is it composed of other materials?

Comment: Yes.  ----------

Comment: yes and yes.... active part is silicon... a lot of other crap though http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/MaterialComposition.do?searchParts=1N5821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N5820-D.PDF):

> This series employs the Schottky Barrier principle in a large area
>   metal-to-silicon power diode.

Comment: The metal is identified in the data sheet: 'chrome barrier', presumably meaning chromium.